# Initialize react interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an interface:

```
export interface Fren {
  name: string;
}
```

and an array of strings: `frens: string[]`
How to convert `frens` of `string[]` to `Fren[]`?

My attempt:

```
frens.map(f => ({name: f})
```

But the result of that operation is `Object[]`

Comment: are you trying to convert `frens` ? or you want to get a new Fren[] object?

Comment: it doesn't matter for me

Answer (score 1):

You can type the return value of the callback

```
frens.map((f): Fren => ({ name: f }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `as` syntax. The `as` keyword is a Type Assertion in TypeScript which tells the compiler to consider the object as another type than the type the compiler infers the object to be.

```
const result:Fren[] = frens.map(f => ({name: f} as Fren)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes